# How would I redirect the main html page to another html page when I login?

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a main page in html with a login box where if you put a password whose length is 8 or more it displays a message which says "Login successful" or "Login failed" otherwise. So far so good because I have tested it and it works, but when I press the "OK" button after I successfully log in, it doesn't redirect me to the new page I have created.

Below is the code for the function where `window.location.replace("admin.html")` is the only line which is not working. I have tried using the line with "href" instead of this one with "replace", but still it doesn't work. The new html page where I want to go is created in the same folder as the main one, and I've also tried including the full path of the page URL, but still no result.

```
function validate(){
    var password=document.getElementById("pass");
    var length=document.getElementById("length");
    
    if(password.value.length >= 8){
        alert("Login successful!");
        window.location.replace('admin.html');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        alert("Login failed!");
    }
}
```

Update: HTML code

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">   
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/image1.png">
                <h1 style="color: white;">ONLINE LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">BOOKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">USER-LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ADMIN-LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <br><br><br>
            <div class="box">
                <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>Welcome!</h1><br>
                <form>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"><br>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="pass"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="validate()"><br>
                    <a href="#">Forgot Your Password</a><br>
                    <a href="#">Create New Account</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <p id="length"></p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <br><br>
            <p style="color: white; text-align: center;">
                Email
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and it's working. I  assume you messed up with the location.href

```
   function validate(){
    var password=document.getElementById("pass");
    var length=document.getElementById("length");

    if(password.value.length >= 8){
        alert("Login successful!");
        window.location.href = "admin.html";
    }
    else{
      alert("Login failed!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It does not work for me. The new window does not open when I click the "OK" button. I tried it again to be sure.

Comment: It's not supposed to work on the click of the ok button. It's an alert

Comment: How do I open the new page after a successful login then?

Comment: You mean a new window? Or a new tab? Or simply load the page in the same tab?

Comment: I want to load the new page in the same tab where the main one is after I successfully log in.

Comment: Can you update the question with your html?

Comment: I updated the question. Can you give me any contact of yours like social media for example or something else, because stackoverflow is warning me for extended comments and I also have a new account here so not enough credit to move the discussion to chat?

Comment: m.me/iamjoydey or LinkedIn.com/in/joy-dey